# There was an error in a part of the date format. [ Expression (if known) = ]

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to save date in my database' datetime field.
My variable catches date as

```
vrDteTimePprBgn As Date = Today.Date
```

then I save it as
drNewRowMCQsAns.Item("DTE") = vrDteTimePprBgn

At runtime, I get error 
There was an error in a part of the date format. [ Expression (if known) =  ]
Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: locale: US versus non-US date?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Function SQLDate(ByVal DT As Date)
    Dim FDay As Byte = DT.Day
    Dim FMonth As Byte = DT.Month
    Dim FYear As Integer = DT.Year
    Dim FHour As Byte = DT.Hour
    Dim FMin As Byte = DT.Minute
    Dim FSec As Byte = DT.Second

    SQLDate = FYear & "-" & FMonth & "-" & FDay  & " " & FHour & ":" & FMin & ":" & FSec 
End Function
```

The resul is in String format but it works
sorry for my bad English